# Geograpy - two sentences with same province name return different results

Tags: python, geograpy

May anyone help me to explain the reason of these two text with same information but geograpy3 can only detect province name in 1 sentence?

```
a = geograpy.get_geoPlace_context(text='I live in Gauteng South Africa')
a.other --> ['Gauteng']

b = geograpy.get_geoPlace_context(text='Gauteng South Africa')
b.other --> [] --> is it wrong?
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Geography need to know what is the location in the sentence, adding the "in" on the first example indicate the location should be right after. This sentence will do the same result: `'In Gauteng South Africa'`.

For the second sentence Geography cannot tell if the location is 'Gauteng' or 'South Africa' so it answer nothing, using only `'Gauteng'` will answer right.